# How can I use SlidingUpPanel on a ListView in Flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

In my app, I'm using a **ListView** nested in TabView. I want to add an **SlidingUpPanel** so I used this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) and when I implemented it the **ListView** crashed. So how can I solve this?

[Before the implementation of the SlidingUpPanel widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Goz6w.png)

[After implementing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq3dQ.png)

**[The repo](https://github.com/OmarYehiaDev/E-Soor)**, You will find the exact code in :-

> lib/tabs/store.dart

Comment: are you using the Nesting the SlidingUpPanel Stack implementation?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla I don't think so :"(

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @SaedNabil Which piece of code do you need to see exactly?

Comment: @SaedNabil I also updated the question with link of the repo and the place of the code

Comment: @omarYehiaTawfeek check your repo for pull request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by moving the sliding up panel from bottom navigation and put it in the stack OnTop of the list .